How to use parametric plot for the following two equations?
I have the following two equations
eq = 4 Ω^2 + 2 u 2 Ω Sin [τ + ω ϵ τ] == (m L ( 1 + R/q))^2 + 4 ω^2 - A^2 - u^2 - 2 u A Cos [ τ + ω ϵ τ];

k = -(2 Ω + 
        u  Sin[τ + ω ϵ τ]) m L q  1/( 
     0.5 m L) (-2 Ω + 
       u  Sin[τ + ω ϵ τ] - 
       2 ω ) + (m L  1/( 
       0.5 m L) (-2 Ω1 + 
         u  Sin[τ + ω ϵ τ] - 
         2 ω ))^2 q  - (u  Cos[τ + ω ϵ \
τ] + u  α - 27/4 γ  u  q^2 - η - 
       m ) (m L q  1/( 
       0.5 m L ) (-u  Cos[τ + ω ϵ τ] - 
         u  α + 9/4 γ  u  q^2 + η + m )) + (m L 1/(
        0.5 m L ) (-u  Cos[τ + ω ϵ τ] - 
         u  α + 9/4 γ  u  q^2 + η + m ))^2 q == 0;

Both equations contain u and Capital Omega, How do I plot Capital Omega in x axis and u in y axis, I can vary q. How to use parametric plot. The parameter values are
τ = 6.3; G = 11; α = 0.5; γ = 0.5; Q = 25;
m = 0.05; μ = G/Q; L = 1;  η = 0.04; ϵ = 0.1;
ω = 0.02; R = 0.08; A=0.5;R=0.08

Here eq is a quadratic equation, there are two solutions for capital omega.  Now once I obtain Ω, if K>0 satisfies I have to plot again u with capital omega from the following equation
k2 = u  Cos[τ + ω ϵ τ] + u α - 
   27/4 γ u  q^2 - η - m - 
   1/( m L ) (-u Cos[τ + ω ϵ τ] - 
      u α + 9/4 γ u q^2 + η + m ) == 0

So first I have to plot Ω and u , from k==0 then I have to plot Ω and u from k2==0, if k>0 condition satisfies. My confusion both u and Ω are unknown in eq and k.

In your case, it is possible to get explicit solutions for $u$ and $\Omega$ by using SolveValues. Then you can use ParametricPlot with $q$ as a parameter. However, I cannot make it work because you didn't give us the value of $\Omega_1$.

You have 4 free variables: \[CapitalOmega],\[CapitalOmega]1,u,q. You need to specify \[CapitalOmega]1,q to draw what you want.

Sorry it was a typo error,  it is capital omega only

What about "q"?

$Version

(* "14.0.0 for Mac OS X ARM (64-bit) (December 13, 2023)" *)

Clear["Global`*"]

eq = 4  Ω^2 + 
     2  u  2  Ω  Sin[τ + ω  ϵ  τ] == \
(m  L  (1 + R/q))^2 + 4  ω^2 - A^2 - u^2 - 
     2  u  A  Cos[τ + ω  ϵ  τ] //
   Simplify;

k = -(2  Ω + 
          u   Sin[τ + ω  ϵ  τ])  m  L  q   1/(0.5  \
m  L)  (-2  Ω + 
         u   Sin[τ + ω  ϵ  τ] - 
         2  ω) + (m  L   1/(0.5  m  L)  (-2  Ω + 
            u   Sin[τ + ω  ϵ  τ] - 
            2  ω))^2  q - (u   Cos[τ + ω  ϵ  \
τ] + u   α - 27/4  γ   u   q^2 - η - 
         m)  (m  L  q   1/(0.5  m  L)  (-u   Cos[τ + ω  \
ϵ  τ] - u   α + 9/4  γ   u   q^2 + η + 
           m)) + (m  L  1/(0.5  m  L)  (-u   Cos[τ + ω  \
ϵ  τ] - u   α + 9/4  γ   u   q^2 + η + 
            m))^2  q == 0 //
    Rationalize // FullSimplify;

param = {τ -> 6.3, G -> 11, α -> 0.5, γ -> 0.5, Q -> 25, 
    m -> 0.05, μ -> G/Q,
    L -> 1, η -> 0.04, ϵ -> 0.1, ω -> 0.02, R -> 0.08, 
    A -> 0.5, R -> 0.08} //
   Rationalize;

eq2 = {eq, k} /. param // FullSimplify;

To plot equations, use ContourPlot
Manipulate[q = Rationalize[qv];
 plt = ContourPlot[Evaluate[eq2],
   {Ω, -0.25, 0.25}, {u, -1, 0},
   FrameLabel -> (Style[#, 14] & /@ {Ω, u}),
   MaxRecursion -> 3,
   ImageSize -> 360];
 pts = NSolveValues[eq2, {Ω, u}, Reals,
    WorkingPrecision -> 15] // N;
 Show[plt,
  Graphics[{Red, AbsolutePointSize[5],
    Tooltip[Point[#], #] & /@ pts}]],
 {{qv, 0.96, "q"}, 0.94, 0.995, 0.0005,
  Appearance -> "Labeled"},
 SynchronousUpdating -> False,
 TrackedSymbols -> {qv}]


